# Find the ROW number in excel with multiple matching criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to be able to find the row number of the row where matching criteria from `A1` is equal or greater than values in column `C` and lesser or equal than values in column `D`

I can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` combo but not sure if this is something I should use for multiple criteria matching.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if multiple valid combinations are found?

Comment: Basically, I will use the row number to obtain value from Column E

Comment: So it should just return the first valid row?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would not use `MATCH` to get the row number since you have multiple criteria.  I would still use `INDEX` however to get the value of the row in E once the proper row number was discovered.

So instead of `MATCH` I would use an array formula using an `IF` statement that contained multiple criteria.  Now note that array formulas need to be entered using `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`.  The `IF` statement would look like this:

```
=IF((A1>=C:C)*(A1<=D:D),ROW(A:A),"")
```

*Note: I did not use the `AND` formula here because that cannot take in arrays.  But since booleans are just 1's or 0's in Excel, multiplying the criteria works just fine.*

This now gives us an array containing only blanks and valid row numbers.  Such that if rows 5 and 7 were both valid the array would look like:

```
{"","","","",5,"",7,"",...}
```

Now if we encapsulate that `IF` statement with a `SMALL` we can get whatever valid row we want.  In this case since we just want the first valid row we can use:

```
=SMALL(IF((A1>=C:C)*(A1<=D:D),ROW(A:A),""),1)
```

Which if the first valid row is 5 then that will return 5.  Incrementing the `K` value of the `SMALL` formula will allow you to grab the 2nd, 3rd, etc valid row.

Now of course since we have the row number a simple `INDEX` will get us the value in column E:

```
=INDEX(E:E,SMALL(IF((A1>=C:C)*(A1<=D:D),ROW(A:A),""),1))
```

Comment: Brilliant. And using LARGE() allows to find the last row matching the criteria.

Comment: @chancea  any reason using `SMALL(exp,1)` instead of `MIN(exp)` ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez It's just up to your development needs.  If you never change it then `SMALL(exp,1)` and `MIN(exp)` are the same

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match more than one column value to retrieve a row number, that is, if two or more columns together create a unique ID you can use an array formula with MATCH as below:

```
MATCH(1,(A:A=J1)*(B:B=K1)*(C:C=L1),0)
```

where A, B, C contain the column array to be matched to retrieve the unique row number corresponding to the value in J1, K1, L1 respectively.

For a step-by-step guide, [Christian Pedersen's Explainer](https://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/)