# Excel: Find matching row with numerical range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with Company Name and Serial Number columns. The serial number column values are in range e.g. 1001-2000. How do I look up company name from a specific serial number value? See this screenshot for example.

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

Column B can be split into two columns if needed though it is preferable to have single column.

I tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488091/find-the-row-number-in-excel-with-multiple-matching-criteria) but got a #Spill! error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, using Lookup+Imreal function

In `E2`, enter formula:

```
=LOOKUP(D2,IMREAL(B2:B5&"i"),A2:A5)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer.  Never heard of IMREAL before, I thought it was a UDF until I looked it up.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with this... It is a crude hack.

```
=IF(D2<=1000,A2,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2+1&"-"&D2,B:B,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

in the special case of the ranges all ending at a multiple of 1000 and each band being essentially 1000 units you could go with the special case formula of

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,INT(($D2-1)/1000)+1)
```

Note that you don't actually use the info in column B for this option.  It is based purely on the pattern to the range breakdown

if you want to restrict it to values between 1 and 4000 you could wrap it in an if statement that checks for that.

```
=IF(AND(D2>=1,D2<=4000),INDEX($A$2:$A$5,INT(($D2-1)/1000)+1),"SN out of range")
```

[image: POC]