# Excel Finding the Row Number based on Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to get the Row number based on a date.

I've built a calendar in Excel on one sheet while using another sheet as a table where `A1:NB1` are dates.

Example:
[image]

I am using the following formula to give me the column number associated with the day I have cells selected `=IFERROR(MATCH(M3,INDIRECT("'"&ScYear&"'!A1:NB1",TRUE),0),"")`

Example:
[image]

I'd like a way to identify the row number selected on the calendar with the first available row in the tables date column.

For example if I select the first cell on today's date in the calendar it reports row 1 since that's the first blank cell. If I were to select the second cell down under today's date it would select the second row all they way to the 9th row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the ROW number in excel with multiple matching criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488091/find-the-row-number-in-excel-with-multiple-matching-criteria)

Comment: @bonCodigo not really. This is dealing with multiple criteria and dealing with variables such as great then and less than. I need a simple match on date and then match the row numbers 2-9. I'll keep messing with my formulas. Thanks though!

Comment: *"If I were to select the second cell down under today's date it would select the second row all they way to the 9th row."* Are you looking for a formula or a mouse click action?

Comment: I was thinking/hoping there was a formula I could use similar to the one I have for the Columns. But yeah I could use VBA to write a click event to give me the row number as well.

Comment: @Deke so then it gives you a base for a desired solution, such that 1) find a row number based on a criteria 2) criteria to match can be a single date/value or multiples 3) shouldn't your question be edited as "find the first available *blank* row based on a criteria (date value)"? 4) what are the values of your arguments in this formula? And what do you get as output? `INDIRECT("'"&ScYear&"'!A1:NB1",TRUE)`?

Comment: @bonCodigo yeah you could look at it that way. The criteria for my indirect function is the dates. But I've decided to use a less elegant solution and I've written VBA code on selection change that forces the correct number of the row I want to use. After further research I think this is the best way cause I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is even possible at this point.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you trying to do tbh - could you pls. just give a few e.g.s of the output you expect to see if yo select cells 2-9, 11-whatever the next penultimate blank before 17th is (and include row labels in screenshots so I don't have to count 22 rows to be sure I'm understanding).  Although I don't quite understand (because comparability to unknown formula names corresponding to your column function is indeterminable), I have a curious feeling that it can be done with a simple mod + match function - but need to be clear/understand without ambiguity "output" desired for....TBC

Comment: very clearly defined "inputs" / "actions"... else if you're happy with the VBA soln, is there still a need for this Q/post(?) - regardless, it could benefit others, so make the polite request to confirm/clarify the goal per above.  ta (PS - would also advise / request giving a clear / precise formulation for the formula names you've included for the column function - especially since this appears to be the only 'quasi-' concrete lead to figure out what it is that you're really trying to achieve (from my persp. at least).  My goal / intention is to help you with this Q - just ned to clarify 1st

Comment: @JB-007 My VBA solution works, less elegant than I wanted but it does what I need. So that said this post could be closed. I was also thinking that at some stage I would research setting up a mod that could run a match function or something like that but for now I'm satisfied with my current results. If you want to leave this post open I can get more specific on the original ask.

Comment: Sure I don't mind - I'm actually curious RE: the precise prob because I have it sounds like its something that an index(<somelist>, mod(match(<list1: need more info>, <list2: ditto>,0), num_rows(e.g. 9)_more info)) could solve - but need to understand what goes into "more info" and whether this is what you're after or not - but anyways, glad to hear that you have a VB soln.. (the code for that might give a decent explanation as to what it is that you're tying to achieve, or some sample output and Qs in my pvs comment) - I leave it to you if you think the fn, will help

Answer (score 0):

In VBA I used this long and in-elegant solution to get the row I wanted based on `target.value`.

By "Manually" having it identify the the selected target.address I can then have it identify the selected row and write that value to `Range("M43")` I then use code like the following `Sheets("" & DbSht & "").Cells(DbRow + 1, DbCol).Value = Target.Value` identify the column and row needed to be updated. (DbRow = the value in M43 and DbCol = the value in M42 which is the column number and row number).

There may be an easier way with index or Match through a module but this solution works for now. Hopefully this makes more sense than my original question.

Just a sample of the code not the whole thing, it's too long:

```
If Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 7 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 8 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 9 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 11 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 13 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 15 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 16 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 17 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 18 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 21 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 22 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 24 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 1
Range("B7").Value = Target.Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 25 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 2
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 26 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 3
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-2, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 27 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 4
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-3, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 28 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 5
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-4, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 29 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 6
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-5, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 30 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 7
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-6, 0).Address

ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 5 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 6 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 7 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 8 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 9 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
ElseIf Target.Row = 31 And Target.Column = 10 Then
Range("M43").Value = 8
Range("B7").Value = Target.Offset(-7, 0).Address
End If
```